# NullPointerException in Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest

Tags: java, networking, libgdx

I have tried to write a little code using libGDX to work with network. Here's a code:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String accessToken = "********"; //a set of symbols, not important because it is specific of request target
    String userID = "*********"; //also not important
    String message = "Hello World";
    String uri = "method/wall.post?owner_id=" + userID + "&message=" + message + "&access_token=" + accessToken;
    HttpRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new HttpRequestBuilder();
    HttpRequest httpRequest = requestBuilder.newRequest().method(HttpMethods.GET).url("https://api.vk.com/").content(uri).build();
    Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(httpRequest, //Here Eclipse shows NullPointerException
            null); //But not here
}
```

If I write this URL in browser, it works right. It means, that the problem on my side. How to fix it?

Summary of values of the object which causes NullPointerException:

[image: debugger screenshot]

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace? Is there maybe something with the giving "null" parameter

Comment: Did you use a debugger?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing this code in the static main entry point of your program. Your Gdx is not yet loaded,so `Gdx` is still null at this point.

Create a none static class and put your code in it's constructor and initialize that class within this static entry point.

```
public class WebTest()
{
  public WebTest()
  {
    String accessToken = "********"; //a set of symbols, not important because it is specific of request target
    String userID = "*********"; //also not important
    String message = "Hello World";
    String uri = "method/wall.post?owner_id=" + userID + "&message=" + message + "&access_token=" + accessToken;
    HttpRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new HttpRequestBuilder();
    HttpRequest httpRequest = requestBuilder.newRequest().method(HttpMethods.GET).url("https://api.vk.com/").content(uri).build();
    Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(httpRequest, //Here Eclipse shows NullPointerException
            null); //But not here
  }
}

public class Test {    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new WebTest();
  }
}
```

Comment: No effect. I've just copied your code but there's still NPException.

Comment: So what exactle is `Null`? I would surely guess it is `Gdx` without a stacktrace. Are you sure you have your project setup correctly since you should not even get to code in the entry point for a `LibGDX` project `static main(String[] args) { ... }` but just in the core module where `GameName extends ApplicationListener / Game`.